# Why is ADSL2 speed throttled on Draytek Vigor 2830N V1

Tags: networking, router

I have a Draytek Vigor 2830N ADSL2+ router.  My ISP reckoned broadband should be about 20Mbps, but I am only getting ~10Mbps.  The signal never drops out, but is always down at around 10, even when I only have one item connected to the router.

I have done a factory reset and there is no change.

I have also tried a different router and it gets 20Mbps no problem.

Is there something with the default settings on this particular router that throttle the connection or is it at my ISP?

Comment: "Signal drops out" sounds like Wi-Fi; have you tried a wired connection to the same router?

Comment: Most likely your ISP but there is not enough information in your question to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: @grawity it is wired, I just used the wrong phrase.

Comment: @DavidPostill it turns out that you were right.

Comment: @RobMason I mostly am ;) What did your ISP say?

Comment: @DavidPostill Have added as the answer in case anyone else has similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the connection had been "banded" by BT due to a lot of recent power failures and router restarts in a short space of time.  Having spoken to them, they have removed the banding to allow the speed to rise back up to the appropriate level.  The 20Mbps on the second router was a coincidence as it dropped to the lower level for all routers shortly after posting.

Thanks

Comment: Is your ISP BT or a reseller? If it is BT that is an amazing response :)

Comment: @DavidPostill it is BT, although it is a business line as I wanted a fixed IP.  The customer service has been great from them

Comment: Ah. That explains it. There are many many complaints about BT customer services for **residential** customers.